# How to delete only one row in tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter

when i run app and delete one row is worked but whene i close the app to update, all rows are deleted

what should i do

```
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class root(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.bookInfodb = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
        self.c = self.bookInfodb.cursor()
        self.bookInfodb.commit()
        self.c.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS books (title TEXT, author TEXT, year TEXT, isbn TEXT)")
        self.title("book info")
        self.minsize(500, 400)
        self.configure(background="gray")
        self.datas()
        self.fetch()

    def fetch(self):
        self.c.execute("SELECT * FROM books")
        rows = self.c.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            self.list_box.insert(END, row)

    def delete_item(self):
        selected_item = self.list_box.curselection()
        for item in selected_item:
            self.list_box.delete(item)
        self.c.execute("DELETE FROM books")
        self.bookInfodb.commit()

    def addData(self, title, years, author, isbn):

        self.c.execute(
            "INSERT INTO books VALUES (?,?,?,?)", (
                self.title.get(),
                self.years.get(),
                self.author.get(),
                self.isbn.get()))
        self.bookInfodb.commit()

    def datas(self):
        self.title = StringVar()

        self.titleEntry = ttk.Label(self, text="titel")
        self.titleEntry.place(x=41, y=10)

        entry = Entry(self, textvariable=self.title)
        entry.place(x=66, y=10)

        # make years input

        self.years = StringVar()

        self.yearsEntry = ttk.Label(self, text="years")
        self.yearsEntry.place(x=269, y=10)

        entry2 = Entry(self, textvariable=self.years)
        entry2.place(x=300.5, y=10.2)

        # make author input

        self.author = StringVar()

        self.authorEntry = ttk.Label(self, text="author")
        self.authorEntry.place(x=40, y=51)

        entry3 = Entry(self, textvariable=self.author)
        entry3.place(x=80, y=51)

        # make isbn input

        self.isbn = StringVar()

        self.isbnEntry = ttk.Label(self, text="isbn")
        self.isbnEntry.place(x=270, y=52)

        entry_iv = Entry(self, textvariable=self.isbn)
        entry_iv.place(x=297, y=52)

        # listbox

        self.list_box = Listbox(self, height=10, width=50)
        self.list_box.place(x=85, y=200)

        # buttons

        save_button = Button(
            self,
            text=" save ",
            command=(
                lambda t=self.title.get(), y=self.years.get(), a=self.author.get(), i=self.isbn: self.addData(t, y, a, i)),)

        save_button.place(x=66, y=150)

        delete_button = Button(self, text="delete", command=self.delete_item)
        delete_button.place(x=215, y=150)



    windows = root()
    windows.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is far to much code. This question needs a [mcve]. I recommend you start with a script that does nothing but create a database, inserts some data, and then deletes one row, without any of the tkinter code.

Comment: Try using the following just before deleting the `item` from the list box: `self.c.execute("DELETE FROM books WHERE title = ? AND author = ? and year = ? AND isbn = ?", self.list_box.get(item))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the problem but `self.c.execute("DELETE FROM books")` will delete the entire books table.

You probably need to add a `WHERE` clause in your DELETE statement

```
self.c.execute("DELETE FROM books WHERE ...")
```

Comment: thanks but is not worked

Comment: Can you show us how you modify the DELETE statement?